# Tiangong-1 reentry

Tags: reentry, tiangong-1

I’m trying to understand what could happen when the Tiangong-1 will reenter the atmosphere (probably on march 2018).

Starting from an initial state obtained from a TLE, I integrate the position and velocity vectors of the Tiangong-1 until the reentry date.
I do the same for each TLE I downloaded so far and here is the result:

[image: Tiangong-1 reentry]

The graph shows 65 possible trajectories based on 65 TLEs.

Next, I integrated few trajectories down to the ground to see the so called max q (maximum dynamic pressure) encountered during reentry.
According to my simulation, the max q should not exceed 11 kPa (usually I get 5 to 8 kPa). Just for comparison, the max q for the Saturn V was 35 kPa and for the Space Shuttle it was 28 kPa.
I also compared the max q for the TMA-M reentry module in an hypothetical ballistic reentry trajectory (not used during normal reentry), here is what I get:

[image: Reentry comparison]

Since the Tiangong-1 max q is very small, I think that some "hard" components (like engine nozzles) will survive to the reentry. What do you think? Any comment?

Comment: Likely, similarly to [Skylab reentry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skylab#Re-entry), a lot of the station, while badly scorched and torn apart by the aero forces, will just rain down on Earth.

Comment: Very interesting question! I think a separate question about the limitations of using TLEs to propagate to re-entry 240 days into the future would be interesting as well. That different TLEs tend to give similar results doesn't confirm the calculation is correct, but that's a separate question. The problem here is that your question is "What do you think? Any comment?" and that "doesn't fly" as a proper stackexchange question. Try to ask something that has a fact-based answer. You can [take the SE tour](https://space.stackexchange.com/tour) and look around at other questions here.

Comment: @uhoh. The TLEs cannot be used to propagate the satellite's state; they can be used to know the state of a satellite for the TLE epoch. The state propagation can be done via SGP/SDP4/8 or by other means. I used a very good integrator (DOPRI853) to propagate the initial state and I included the celestial bodies perturbations, atmospheric drag (using the NRLMSISE-00 model) and Earth's zonal harmonics perturbations. "What do you think?" means: am I right if I think that the max q is too small to burn the Tiangong-1?

Comment: Oh all of that is wonderful! If you look around here you'll see that this kind of information is included in the original question. The more you explain what you have done and what you know, the more effort people will put into answers. Please take a moment and explain this *in the body of your question*. Comments should be thought of as temporary.

Comment: A few thoughts: 1) You do not appear to be accounting for thermal effects, which are significant enough that ideal gas models will give incorrect results. 2) Your max-q depends on your velocity vs. altitude relationship, which is going to depend heavily on the aerodynamic and mass properties of the vehicle -- will it tumble, or will it stabilize into a low- or high-drag orientation?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling there are still four other questions about Tiangong-1 that have the original `Tiangong` tag. Now that you have created a new `Tiangong-1`tag for this question only, there are *three Tiangong tags*. Maybe it would be good to update the other four questions and let the original generic tag "retire"?

Comment: @uhoh Maybe. My reasoning for making a specific tiangong-1 tag was that (a) we already have tiangong-2 for precedent, and (b) this question appears to be *specifically* about Tiangong-1; expertise about Tiangong-2 (or any future one) is unlikely to be directly applicable. On the other hand, we also have e.g. apollo-program, apollo-soyuz and apollo-12, so there's precedent *also* for having both a more generic and a more specific tag coexisting.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I understand, luckily there are only four other questions which now have the "wrong" tag since you've now created the "right" tag. Should take 60-90 seconds to update those four.

Comment: @Tristan I don't understand your point #1; what do you mean? 2) There is no way for the Tiangong-1 to stabilize into an high drag attitude, it surely will reenter with the solar array on stern.

Comment: @Cristiano 1) Do your drag calculations, which affect your altitude-velocity profile, take into account the compressive heating of the air, including deviations from ideal gas models? 2) It will only keep the solar array on the stern until aerothermal loads rip them off, which won't take much.

Comment: @Tristan 1) No, I change the drag coefficient with the altitude, but for the drag calculations I use the "standard" formula: D= .5 rho V*V Cd A / m. Please, do you have a link for the correct formula? 2) For that reason I don't think that the low- high-drag attitude plays a significant role in the simulation, because I suppose that only the "hard" components will survive to the reentry. I think that we should pay attention to the engines, fuel (toxic and carcinogenic) and structural components. Even if my second graph is not perfectly exact, it seems that the max q will be very low.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I've gone ahead and changed those four questions from `Tiangong` to `Tiangong-1`for you.

Comment: @Cristiano may you share your simulation code?